# Filtering LINQ child collection EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Im having some problems trying to do this filtering and im sure it can be done better than what im doing. I will show my classes and how im solving it but i was wondering if I could use Linq to filter this. My Classes:

```
public class Section
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public virtual List<FeatureType> Features { get; set; }
}

public class ItemType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FeatureType> FeatureTypes { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }    
}

public class FeatureType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public Section Section { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ItemType> ItemTypes { set; get; }
}
```

I'm trying to get all Sections, and filter Features by an ItemTypeID, so only the FeatureTypes of that ItemTypes are listed. What Im doing now its just getting all sections, and just do a for and just add the ones that work for me in other:

```
public ItemTypeFeatureViewModel(int myItemTypeId, IUnitOfWork myUnitOfWork)
{
    ItemTypeId = myItemTypeId;
    unitOfWork = myUnitOfWork;
    Sections = unitOfWork.SectionRepository.Get(includeProperties: "Features")
                         .ToList();

    foreach (var item in Sections)
    {
        var x = new List<FeatureType>();
        foreach (var feature in item.Features)
        {
            foreach (var itemType in feature.ItemTypes)
            {
                if (itemType.Id == ItemTypeId)
                {
                    x.Add(feature);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        item.Features = x;
    }
}
```

Can i improve this and avoid all this foreach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't filter out included collection on server side, but you can replace two inner loops with:

```
item.Features = item.Features
                    .Where(f => f.ItemTypes.Any(i => i.Id == ItemTypeId))
                    .ToList();
```

That will select only those features which have at least one item type with id you provided.

Comment: Thats the constructor of ItemTypeFeatureViewModel, i would need the unitOfWork to be in my object, for the Id i think you are right.

Comment: @LuisTellez sorry, my bad. For some reason I thought it is a void method

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Sections
    .ForEach(x => x.Features = x.Features.Where(y => y.Any(z => z.Id == ItemTypeId))
    .ToList());
```

Comment: SelectMany will flatten all features into single collection, but OP wants to filter features of each section separately. Also you are not using feature items to find appropriate features

Comment: I think you are missing a step in, in this case i would be getting the feature with the ID(featureId) of my itemType ID.

Comment: Mea culpa, I've skipped last line of your code. example has been fixed.